# how to convert nsstring to uicolor?

Tags: iphone

I have one string(NSString) in string there is one value like string=@"black" now i want to use textcolore using string.I have written below code.
txtView.textColor=[UIColor string];

But it not working can suggest me?

Comment: `txtView.textColor=[UIColor string]` is completely wrong, show us more of your code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get selector using `NSSelectorFromString` function and then send it to UIColor. You must also test if UIColor is able to respond to the selector you have to avoid error:

```
SEL blackSel = NSSelectorFromString(@"blackColor");
UIColor* tColor = nil;
if ([UIColor respondsToSelector: blackSel])
      tColor  = [UIColor performSelector:blackSel];
```

Comment: This is perfect for my use with UIColor+Extensions h/m. My custom UIColor names within this category can now be added to my plist of data.