# How to programmatically change UIColor of view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor

Okay, this question comes through a friend so it might be lost in translation...

Basically we need to change the color on a View. It appears to be stored in `NSString` format, but using a `NSString` to set the `UIColor` doesn't seem to do anything. In other words, if `NSString color` holds the value "redColor" then:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = color;  //does nothing
```

Disclaimer: we are Objective-C/iPhone newbies.

Comment: This question may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027255/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-uicolor

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

You can also give RGB values like

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

All the Best.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tell my friend to try this, but two identical answers seems promising :)

Comment: Small detail but you should be dividing by 255 instead of 256.

Answer (score 1):

The color must be a UIColor object:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll tell my friend to try this, but two identical answers seems promising :)

Answer (score 1):

like this also we can use

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];`

OR do like this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:180.0/256.0 green:180.0/256.0 blue:180.0/256.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add color programmatically is by using **ColorLiteral**.

Just add the property ColorLiteral as shown in the example, Xcode will prompt you with a whole list of colors which you can choose. The advantage of doing so is lesser code, **add HEX values or RGB**. You will also get the recently used colors from the storyboard.

**Example:**
**self.view.backgroundColor = ColorLiteral**
[image]