# not sure how I would do this with objectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert nsstring to uicolor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027255/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-uicolor)

not an objective-c programmer but am not sure if I can't do something like this. I know I'm returning a string value but just want a terse way of getting at these values:

```
NSMutableArray *colorsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[colorsArray addObject:@"whiteColor"];
[colorsArray addObject:@"blueColor"];
 // val5 is either 0 or 1
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor [colorsArray objectAtIndex:val5]]];
```

Is this possible?

thx in advance

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Jeremy1026 That won't even compile.

Comment: doesn't compile - `Expected identifier` at that line

Comment: @timpone - your example doesn't work because because the `NSString` instance in the array doesn't specify a selector for the instance method on `UIColor`.  You can use `NSSelectorFromString(...)` to dynamically create the selector at runtime.  Vide infra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you store directly colors instead of `NSString`?

```
NSMutableArray *colorsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[colorsArray addObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[colorsArray addObject:[UIColor blueColor]];
if (val5 < colorsArray.count) // Doesn't hurt any to be safe, and this way you won't get a crash if something messes up your val5 at some point
{
    // val5 is either 0 or 1
    [view setBackgroundColor:[colorsArray objectAtIndex:val5]];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error - Color not expected - leaving color the way it is.")
}
```

You code as it is doesn't compile, syntax is invalid since you are trying to do `[UIColor @"whiteColor"]` which is not a valid syntax. You could use `performSelector:` but this is senseless unless you really need to store colors as strings.

Comment: could certainly do that - was curious if there was a shorter way though; maybe / probably not

Answer (score 3):

Or if you must use `NSString` instances in the array:

```
NSMutableArray *colorsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[colorsArray addObject:@"whiteColor"];
[colorsArray addObject:@"blueColor"];

SEL colorSelector = NSSelectorFromString([colorsArray objectAtIndex:val5]);
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor performSelector:colorSelector]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *colorsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[colorsArray addObject:@"whiteColor"];
[colorsArray addObject:@"blueColor"];
UIColor *color = [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([colorsArray objectAtIndex:1])];
view.backgroundColor = color;
```